# What to do if a user attempts to login via facebook when they've never registered?

Tags: login, registration

We have an app that that allows you to register via email, facebook, or Google account.

If a user attempts to sign in to our app via Facebook or Google when they have never registered with their facebook/google account what would be the best UX ?

I've seen websites that simply register the user and log them in as a new user.

This is not possible for us because our app has two user roles (like dribbble.com). We ask the user which role they want to be before they are registered.

Right now I've come up with two possible solutions:

1. Refresh the **sign_in** page with a notification to the user that his associated fb/google account was never registered
2. Redirect the user to the **sign_up** page with a notification that they're account was not found and to please sign up.

Please note that our sign in page is unified so we don't know which role they're signing in as.

Comment: Do you mean when they don't have a facebook account, or their facebook account doesn't correspond to an account on your system?

Comment: When their facebook account doesn't correspond to an account on my system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that even though they are fully authenticated, you still need to prompt with a "registration" screen to get their profile preferences.  Something like:

> Hello XX_New_User,
>
> We are not able to find an existing account for this username.
>
> - Would you like to create a new account for XX_New_User?
>
> If you believe you already have an account, maybe it is associated with a different
> Facebook/Google username?  If so, click "cancel" and log in with another username.
>
> If you have an account and you would like to *add* this username to that account,
> then click "cancel", log in with the old username, and use the Add options to add this username.

If they choose to create a new account, then of course you prompt for whatever preferences you need to record at that time.

I worked on a system for a long time where we transparently and automatically made new accounts whenever a new person logged in, but this was a **problem**.  Someone would log in with their Facebook ID and set up a bunch of stuff.  Later, they would log in with their Google ID and without their knowing it, get a new, empty account.  They thought the system had lost all their settings.  *It is critical that you let the user know when you are creating a new account, and make this a distinct action.*

**Analysis**

Using cloud-based SSO techniques requires you to turn around the thinking on the normal registration process.  In a "traditional" application, when a user registers their authentication credentials (password), they also set some preferences in their "profile" in the same step.  Both the authentication credentials and profile information are often kept in the same place.

When a program leverages Facebook/Google to do the authentication, it does not need to gather a password, but it still has to gather information for their profile. If it doesn't find a profile (e.g. an account) then it must prompt them to create one.  The prompt is important because they may have multiple online logins, and they may have used the wrong one.

**Trap:** Some programmers jump to the conclusion that saying whether a person has a profile or not is a security risk / information leak.  In a "traditional" application, you would never say whether a user exists or not to an unauthenticated visitor.  However, there is no security risk here because after authentication from Facebook/Google, you know for certain that the user is a specific person.  Even though you do not have an account for the person, because of the SSO, you do have assurance that only the person in question can see the result.  I mention it here because this is a common mistake among good software architects.

Note that the message offers to *add* a login to the profile.  In a "traditional" application, there is only one identity per profile, but when you use SSO, there will be the possibility that someone will want to *change* their identity in the future, and keep their profile information.  Just because I change my Google ID does not mean that I want to set everything up in your application again.  There should be multiple logins (usernames) in a profile, and there should be a way to add and delete them.  Be sure that they are properly authenticated before making any of these changes.

I cover some other aspects of migrating an application from a "traditional" mode, into a SSO mode, in my blog post  [SSO: What is it?](http://agiletribe.wordpress.com/2012/12/01/sso-what-is-it/)

Answer (score 1):

Your message and response to your users should **indicate what you know**, not what you presume.  If someone tries to sign in with Facebook or Google's authentication and that authentication fails, you should simply let them know that they failed to sign in with that method and give them whatever other information you definitely have.  You should also suggest possible causes and link them to solutions to this.

Something along these lines:

> Your email and password weren't recognised by Google.
>
> Please check that they are correct and try again.
>
> If you haven't registered for a Google account yet, you can get one for free at **accounts.google.com**.

Comment: This is what I started to write as well. OP does not want to know how to handle someone that has already registered using for example Google and now logs in using Facebook.

Comment: @MarjanVenema The question isn't clear, but I can see how that may be the meaning.  I've tried to clarify it with the Op and will amend my answer once he clarifies the question.

Comment: You are way more helpful than I on this Easter Sunday. :-)

Comment: Yeah my bad. This is a good answer, but not exactly what I was asking. Thanks though.